# Lipschutz Ex. 5.9

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume, $S = \{v_1, ..., v_m\}$ contains a linearly dependent subset $\{v_1, ..., v_r\}$. Show that also $S$ is linearly dependent.

My approach is this:

From the assumption it follows that
$$
av_1 + \cdots + rv_r = 0
$$

for $a, ..., r$ not all being zero. Therefore we can say that also
$$
av_1 + \cdots + rv_r + xv_{r+1} + \cdots + mv_m = 0
$$
for $a, ..., r, x, ..., m$ not all being zero (while the coefficients $x, ..., m$ might all be zero). And so $S$ must be linearly dependent.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: You could instead just directly set the coefficients of $v_{r+1},\dots, v_{m}$ to zero and show the non-trivial linear combination.

Comment: I'm actually even happy that my argument does not make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is essentially correct, but you can improve the notation and style.  Suppose that $\{v_1, v_2, \cdots v_r\}$ is linearly dependent. Then there exist
$a_1, a_2, \cdots a_r$ that are not all zero so that
$$\sum_{k=1}^r a_k v_k = 0.$$
Now put $a_k = 0$, $r < k \le m$.  You have
$$\sum_{k=1}^m a_k v_k = 0,$$
with not all of $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_m$ being zero.  Hence 
$\{v_1, v_2, \cdots v_m\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Do you mean to write $v+2$ or do you want to write $v_2$? Am I getting that right, you're doing essentially what I did except for using $\Sigma$s.